# Calculate percentage change in dataframe from first row

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to calculate the per cent change in my dataframe using the first row as the reference. For example my dataframe

```
Set  rate  field
 A     3     10
 B     2     17
 C     5     4
```

Using row A as the reference, I want to calculate the percentage change from row A to every other row for all columns in the dataframe. 
which will result in

```
Set  rate  field      
 A     3     10 
 B    -33    70
 C    66.66  -60

or

Set  rate  field pct_rate   pct-field
 A     3     10     0           0
 B     2     17     -33         70
 C     5     4      66.66       -60
```

My code:

```
 z %>%
   mutate(pct_rate = (rate - lag(rate)/ rate ) * 100)
```

which doesn't give me the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `z$rate[1]` or `z$field[1]` to get the first element and make than the calculations with all values.

```
z$pct_rate <- 100 * (z$rate - z$rate[1]) / z$rate[1]
z$pct_field <- 100 * (z$field - z$field[1]) / z$field[1]
z
#  Set rate field  pct_rate pct_field
#1   A    3    10   0.00000         0
#2   B    2    17 -33.33333        70
#3   C    5     4  66.66667       -60
```

or for many columns:

```
rbind(z[1,], do.call(cbind.data.frame, c(z[1],
 lapply(z[-1], function(x) 100 * (x - x[1]) / x[1])))[-1,])
#  Set      rate field
#1   A   3.00000    10
#2   B -33.33333    70
#3   C  66.66667   -60
```

Answer (score 5):

```
df <- fread("Set  rate  field
 A     3     10
 B     2     17
 C     5     4")
```

Soltuion using `dplyr`: We can use dplyr's `first` function to refer to the first element of a vector (your attempt with `lag` is very close to this solution). Also I used `first(rate)` in the denominator to calculate the percentage difference to get the numbers in your example...

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(pct_rate = (rate - first(rate)) / first(rate)  * 100,
         pct_field = (field - first(field)) / first(field)  * 100)
```

Returns:

```
   Set rate field  pct_rate pct_field
1:   A    3    10   0.00000         0
2:   B    2    17 -33.33333        70
3:   C    5     4  66.66667       -60
```

Comment: As always, tidyverse solutions are more intelligible.